# Python Spark find column differences based on primary key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DF1,

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([(1, "book1", 1), (2, "book2", 2), (3, "book3", 3), (4, "book4", 4)]).toDF(["primary_key", "book", "number"])
```

[image]

and DF2,

```
df2 = sc.parallelize([(1, "book1", 1), (2, "book8", 8), (3, "book3", 7), (5, "book5", 5)]).toDF(["primary_key", "book", "number"])
```

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql import functions
columlist = sc.parallelize(["book", "number"])
```

The result would be, (Vertical way)

```
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

[image]

How can i achieve this in python spark ?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5858851).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `PySpark` solution for it. Mind it, I had to convert `number` to `String`, as we cannot have two different `datatypes` for columns `dataframe1` and `dataframe2` in the resulting `DataFrame` -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, array, struct, lit, col
df1 = sc.parallelize([(1, "book1", 1), (2, "book2", 2), (3, "book3", 3), (4, "book4", 4)]).toDF(["primary_key", "book", "number"])
df1.show()
+-----------+-----+------+
|primary_key| book|number|
+-----------+-----+------+
|          1|book1|     1|
|          2|book2|     2|
|          3|book3|     3|
|          4|book4|     4|
+-----------+-----+------+

df2 = sc.parallelize([(1, "book1", 1), (2, "book8", 8), (3, "book3", 7), (5, "book5", 5)]).toDF(["primary_key", "book", "number"])
df2.show()
+-----------+-----+------+
|primary_key| book|number|
+-----------+-----+------+
|          1|book1|     1|
|          2|book8|     8|
|          3|book3|     7|
|          5|book5|     5|
+-----------+-----+------+

def to_transpose(df, by):

    # Filter dtypes and split into column names and type description
    cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in by))
    # Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns
    assert len(set(dtypes)) == 1, "All columns have to be of the same type"

    # Create and explode an array of (column_name, column_value) structs
    kvs = explode(array([
      struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val")) for c in cols
    ])).alias("kvs")

    return df.select(by + [kvs]).select(by + ["kvs.key", "kvs.val"])

df1_trans = to_transpose(df1.withColumn('number',col('number').cast('string')), ["primary_key"])\
            .withColumnRenamed("val","dataframe1")\
            .withColumnRenamed("key","diff_column_name")
df2_trans=to_transpose(df2.withColumn('number',col('number').cast('string')), ["primary_key"])\
            .withColumnRenamed("val","dataframe2")\
            .withColumnRenamed("key","diff_column_name")

df = df1_trans.join(df2_trans, ['primary_key','diff_column_name'], how='full')
df = df.where((col('dataframe1')!= col('dataframe2')) 
              | (col('dataframe1').isNotNull() & col('dataframe2').isNull()) 
              | (col('dataframe2').isNotNull() & col('dataframe1').isNull())).sort('primary_key')
df = df.show()
+-----------+----------------+----------+----------+
|primary_key|diff_column_name|dataframe1|dataframe2|
+-----------+----------------+----------+----------+
|          2|            book|     book2|     book8|
|          2|          number|         2|         8|
|          3|          number|         3|         7|
|          4|            book|     book4|      null|
|          4|          number|         4|      null|
|          5|            book|      null|     book5|
|          5|          number|      null|         5|
+-----------+----------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Did this address your issue? If so can the question be closed?

Answer (score -1):

I have done it in scala. Hope it helps.

```
val joinDF = df1.join(df2, df1("primary_key") === df2("primary_key"), "full")
  .select(when(df1("primary_key").isNotNull, df1("primary_key")).otherwise(df2("primary_key")).as("primary_key"),
    explode(array(
      map(lit("book"),array(df1("book"), df2("book"))).as("book"),
      map(lit("number"),array(df1("number").cast("string"), df2("number").cast("string"))).as("number")
    )).as("item")
  ).select(col("primary_key"), explode($"item"))
    .select(col("primary_key"),
      col("key").as("diff_column_name"),
      col("value").getItem(0).as("dataframe1"),
      col("value").getItem(1).as("dataframe2")
    ).filter(col("dataframe1").isNull.or(col("dataframe2").isNull).or(col("dataframe1") =!= col("dataframe2")))
```

Here are the results.

`+-----------+----------------+----------+----------+
|primary_key|diff_column_name|dataframe1|dataframe2|
+-----------+----------------+----------+----------+
|2          |book            |book2     |book8     |
|2          |number          |2         |8         |
|3          |number          |3         |7         |
|4          |book            |book4     |null      |
|4          |number          |4         |null      |
|5          |book            |null      |book5     |
|5          |number          |null      |5         |
+-----------+----------------+----------+----------+`